# rpartition, but with two parts only

Tags: ruby

I have a nested path e.g. `backend/docs/file.yml` which I want to split into a `filename` (`file.yml`) and `dir` (`backend/docs`) variables. I wanted to do a similar assignment to the one below, but without the `sep` variable, which is not needed anywhere.

```
dir, sep, filename = params[:path].rpartition("/")
```

`File.basename` and `File.dirname` are not good enough, as they always treat the last string as a filename (`dir` in `backend/docs/dir/` is treated a file, not directory).

Comment: http://ruby-doc.com/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html

Comment: Thanks, but the result is the same as with File - it considers `dir` in `backend/docs/dir/`a file.

Comment: It is odd that there is no default handling for a trailing slash, and it seems like it is nearly always ignored, and there's not even a check for it.

Answer (score 1):

This ought to do it.

```
path = "backend/docs/dir/file.yml"
=> "backend/docs/dir/file.yml"

dir, filename = path.rpartition("/") - ["/"] 
=> ["backend/docs/dir", "file.yml"]
```

Comment: This requires two lines though (could have been one, but not very elegant). I might have been more specific, but I am looking for a method which would just skip the `sep` part. I looked through the Ruby docs and didn't find anything, was hoping I missed something.

Comment: oh.. I get it now. The only other way I can think of is `dir, filename = path.rpartition("/") - ["/"] `. Answer updated.

Comment: I'd like to add `dir, _, filename = path.rpartition('/')`

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah. I don't know how I feel about that. It feels both better and worse at the same time. But `… -['/']` is susceptible to pathological cases like `'//foo'`. I don't think it's quite better. This whole issue is probably just something that is easy to overthink, because ruby often does have a specific method that works exactly as needed. So when we can't find one, it's annoying :).

Comment: @GarrettMotzner But it's much better than `sep`, can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As @Garrett said in the comments you can use 
`dir, _, filename = path.rpartition('/')`

also you can use the built in array method `values_at` and do :

```
dir, filename = path.rpartition('/').values_at(0, -1)
```